# footnote indentation in IEEEtrans template

Tags: footnotes

I am using IEEEtran template for conference papers. I want to add a footnote. I used `\footnote`. But, the footnote at the bottom of the page appear with indentation and dot after the numbering, e.g., `1.`. Ideally, footnotes are just a number without dot nor indentation. My foot note looks like this:

[image]

The normal footnote looks like this:

[image]

How can I make the footnote appear like the second image?

Here is my script:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi


\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\section{Section Contains Footnote}
My text\footnote{My footnote}
% make the title area
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently that's the style IEEE wants for footnotes.

Comment: I think IEEE has changed the style. Just using the `\footnote` command, I am getting the result expected in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Just use `footmisc` package which will redefine the footnote command. Here is the source code:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi


\usepackage[]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\section{Section Contains Footnote}
My text\footnote{My footnote}
% make the title area
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

As an aside, you can customize your footnotes using the command `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{options}`. For example, you can write `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\hspace{0.5mm}\alph{footnote}}` after `\usepackage[]{footmisc}` and you will change the footnote numbering to alphabetical:

[image]

Here, `\hspace{0.5mm}` determines the spacing between the actual text and the footnote symbol in the main text. The best value varies depending on the template and font options you have.